# How to use different implementations in different places with IoC container

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm wondering in how to use different implementations of one interface in different clients.  Here is example situation.

```
public interface IRandomIntGenerator
{
    int Generate();
}

public class SimpleRandomIntGenerator : IRandomIntGenerator
{
    public int Generate()
    {
        return new Random().Next();
    }
}

public class CryptoServiceProviderRandomIntGenerator : IRandomIntGenerator
{
    public int Generate()
    {
        var generator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        generator.GetBytes(bytes);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    }
}
```

Then I've two clients which don't want to know about particular implementations.  One generates log in codes and another chooses random item of an array.

```
public class LogInCodeGenerator
{
    private readonly IRandomIntGenerator randomIntGenerator;

    public LogInCodeGenerator(IRandomIntGenerator randomIntGenerator)
    {
        this.randomIntGenerator = randomIntGenerator;
    }

    public string GenerateCode(int length)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            builder.Append(randomIntGenerator.Generate() % 10);
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}

public class RandomArrayItemChoose
{
    private readonly IRandomIntGenerator randomIntGenerator;

    public RandomArrayItemChoose(IRandomIntGenerator randomIntGenerator)
    {
        this.randomIntGenerator = randomIntGenerator;
    }

    public string Choose(string[] arr)
    {
        return arr[randomIntGenerator.Generate() % arr.Length];
    }
}
```

I want to configure IoC container in such way that it'll use `SimpleRandomIntGenerator` for `RandomArrayItemChoose` and `CryptoServiceProviderRandomIntGenerator` for `LogInCodeGenerator`.

Is there a way to do this with any popular IoC container for .NET?  I especially interested in Windsor Castle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then I've two clients which don't want to know about particular
>   implementations.

It seems as if there is some ambiguity in your design. Those clients might not be interested in the exact implementation, but there seems to be some sort of requirement in your system that `LogInCodeGenerator` must work with cryptographically random numbers.

Since this is a requirement for the system to be secure, it would be better to make the design explicit about this. In other words, you are talking about two separate contracts here:

```
interface IRandomIntGenerator { }

interface ICryptographicRandomIntGenerator { }
```

Not only does this make the intend of the code much clearer, removing this ambiguity from the design makes your DI configuration much simpler.

Comment: I've ended up with empty interfaces inherited from `IRandomIntGenertor`.

Comment: This is only an example.  In most cases interfaces contains several methods.  However, I still feel it like dirty hack.

Comment: @Kirill: "In most cases interfaces contains several methods." In that case you might be violating the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Answer (score 4):

Use Windsor's Service Overrides.  See the section "Supplying the component for a dependency to use" in the [Windsor Docs](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx).

Answer (score 1):

You can name your registered instances and then access them by their name.
In your case, if I understood your question, you want a different injection based on the class that request a resolved instance. 
So you can name your registered instances by the type name of your requesting class.

You will have to `resolve` your instances manually:

```
IRandomIntGenerator generator = container.Resolve<IRandomIntGenerator>(GetType().Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just explicitly declare dependencies:

```
Component.
    For<IRandomIntGenerator>().
    ImplementedBy<SimpleRandomIntGenerator>().
    Named("SimpleRandomIntGenerator"),
Component.
    For<IRandomIntGenerator>().
    ImplementedBy<CryptoServiceProviderRandomIntGenerator>().
    Named("CryptoServiceProviderRandomIntGenerator"),
Component.
    For<RandomArrayItemChoose>().
    DependsOn(Dependency.
        OnComponent("randomIntGenerator", "SimpleRandomIntGenerator")),
Component.
    For<LogInCodeGenerator>().
    DependsOn(Dependency.
        OnComponent("randomIntGenerator", "CryptoServiceProviderRandomIntGenerator")),
```